# How do I convert an std::stringstream to a uintptr_t and maintain the hex value?

Tags: c++

Currently, I am attempting to calculate offsets from a pointer address, and the number of offsets to be calculated can change, so the approach must be done dynamically.

I start by looping for the number of offsets I am trying to calculate, each offset is 4 bytes apart, thus I multiply the current iteration by 4, and then attempt to convert the resulting value to a hex address, and store it back in the `uintptr_t` as a hex value.

This value, in theory, should be the offset I am looking for.

In reality, that is not the case, the value seems to be getting converted back to an integer and stored in the `uintptr_t` variable.

**Expected Output:**

```
4
8
C
10
14
(etc)
```

**Actual Output**

```
4
8
12
16
20
(etc)
```

**Code**

```
for (int i = 1; i < totalEntities + 1; i++)
{
    // Define a stringstream to store the hex value.
    std::stringstream ss;

    // Define a value that will be converted to hex.
    uintptr_t valueToHex = i * 4;

    // Convert valueToHex to Hex, and store the result in stringstream ss.
    ss << std::hex << valueToHex;

    // Convert stringstream ss to a uintptr_t stored in valueToHex
    ss >> valueToHex;

    // Output result
    std::cout << valueToHex << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your EXPECTED and ACTUAL outputs are displaying the SAME VALUES!  The EXPECTED output is displaying the values in **hex** notation, whereas the ACTUAL output is displaying the values in **decimal** notation.  But they are still the SAME VALUES (0x4 = 4, 0x8 = 8, 0xC = 12, 0x10 = 16, 0x14 = 20, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uintptr_t` represents a value of an integer. It does not represent textual representation of that value. The base of the number is not part of the value. `0xC`, `12`, `014` are indistinguishable values regardless of their different representation.

The base is part of the textual representation. All information besides the value (i.e. all representational details) is lost when an integer is extracted from a character stream.

You can either:

a) Extract a string instead, and insert the extracted string into the output stream. Strings retain most of the textual representation (an exception being that system specific new-line character sequences are converted to `\n`) or

b) Use `std::hex` to insert the integer into the output stream in the representation that you want.

Comment: The problem with a) is that putting it into a `std::string` means that I will not be able to add it to a pointer address, as even with converting the `std::string` to a `uintptr_t` the value will be completely different, for example a C will turn into 12 and will be added to the pointer, which will point to a completely different location.

Comment: @UnAlpha Well, if you're going to add the value to a pointer, then why do you care about the textual representation? `pointer + 0xC` and `pointer + 12` point to exactly the same location, because `0xC` and `12` are the same number.

Comment: @UnAlpha In memory, `0xC` and `12` are the same value, represented by the same bytes, behave the same way in arithmetic operations, etc.  You are confusing *storage* with *representation*.

Comment: I see what you guys are saying.  Sorry for stirring up the confusion, I thought thought hex values would behave differently in arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you just want to output an integer as a hex string. ie

```
for (int i = 1; i < numEntities + 1; i++)
{
    std::cout << std::hex<< i*4   << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: No, the output is simply for debugging.  I am trying to get this value as a `uintptr_t` because it is an offset, which I will then add to the pointer address (hence why it must retain the datatype).

Comment: so what are you actually trying to do, the code you show has no inputs and outputs other than the cout of the integers. The 'expected output' shows you want a list of integers displays in hex